# Switching to mysqli from Mysql. Can't get simple query workign

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Decided to move to procedural style coding. I've tried the below code and receive no errors or   returned data. What am I doing wrong? Blanked out the mysqli_connect parameters because I am using a shared server - assume the parameters are correct. Thanks in advance.

```
function login(){
$connect = mysqli_connect("**********", "******", "****", "*****"); 

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `new_base`");
    $bang = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
echo $bang; }
```

NOTE: The call to the function does work echoing a string does get returned to the page.

Comment: use `var_dump()` not `echo` for debugging purposes

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)  is only available with the newer mysqlnd native driver. If you have an older PHP version, you probably don't have mysqlnd.

Comment: @zerkms tried var_dump() still no returned data

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've tried mysqli_num_rows this also doesn't work for me

Comment: @user2631669: `var_dump()` **ALWAYS** returns something. If it didn't return anything - it wasn't run

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: to add, certain *nix OS's such as CentOS did not support mysqlnd in the very recent past.  So although you may have a PHP > 5.3.0 version that was meant to work with mysqlnd, your OS may not provide the necessary driver packages forcing you to compile PHP from scratch.  By now, it's very likely most OS's will provide for this driver or at least reputable package maintainers will.  So not only do you need PHP 5.3.0+, but you also need to make sure your OS version is current.

Comment: Are you sure your connection was established? Try `$connect = mysqli_connect(.....) or die (mysqli_error()); $result = mysqli_query (....) or die (mysqli_error());`